# Output formatting is truncating properties when long strings are present

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I have this script which takes two objects and compares every property and noteproperty, in this case I am trying to compare two ADUser objects returned by `Get-ADUser`:

```
Function Compare-ObjectProperties {
    Param(
        [PSObject]$ReferenceObject,
        [PSObject]$DifferenceObject 
    )


    $objprops = $ReferenceObject | Get-Member -MemberType Property,NoteProperty | % Name
    $objprops += $DifferenceObject | Get-Member -MemberType Property,NoteProperty | % Name
    $objprops = $objprops | Sort | Select -Unique
    $diffs = @()
    foreach ($objprop in $objprops) {
        $diff = Compare-Object $ReferenceObject $DifferenceObject -Property $objprop
        if ($diff) {            
            $diffprops = @{
                PropertyName=$objprop
                RefValue=($diff | ? {$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='} | % $($objprop))
                DiffValue=($diff | ? {$_.SideIndicator -eq '=>'} | % $($objprop))
            }
            $diffs += New-Object PSObject -Property $diffprops
        }        
    }
    if ($diffs) {$diffs | select propertyname,refvalue,diffvalue}
}

$ad1 = Get-ADUser user1 -Properties *
$ad2 = Get-ADUser user2 -Properties *
Compare-ObjectProperties $ad1 $ad2 | select propertyname,refvalue,diffvalue
```

the result is only two fields: propertyname and refvalue. The third field seems to not fit on the screen. `Format-Table -AutoSize` does not change the result at all (I also tried wrap, length, and autosize options).

In fact, even if I use `Out-File result.txt` the result only includes those two columns. I think one of the commands in the script is using formatting that overrides format-table and my other attempts, but I'm not sure which one or how to see.

The script works fine if I compare objects with shorter properties. I can even just use `get-aduser user1` (leaving off `-properties *`)and because the result is much more compact it returns all three fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know there is too much to fit on the screen. `Format-Table -auto` cannot get it to fit and `Out-File` is using the same cmdlets behind the scenes to process that data. Passing objects to `Out-File` will force PowerShell to render the object as a string which it is already having trouble doing. From [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/cookbooks/using-format-commands-to-change-output-view?view=powershell-5.1)

> The Format-Table command assumes that the nearer a property is to the beginning of the property list, the more important it is. So it attempts to display the properties nearest the beginning completely. If the Format-Table command cannot display all the properties, it will remove some columns from the display and provide a warning.

Not sure why you didn't see a warning. I didn't get one either and my `$WarningPreference` should not have prevented it.

Normally this situation happens when have many properties to show and PowerShell uses `Format-List`. I think the threshold for that is 4 but I do not recall. Since you have 3 properties that does not come into play.

So the two things you could do depending on the scenario

#### Output in console

Pipe to `Format-List`

#### Output in file

Use an output format designed for object. `Export-Csv` being the obvious choice

---

### Side Note

Are you *really* comparing *all* properties of these user objects? I get that `-Properties *` is simple to use but it is a performance hog as it queries for non index attributes. If you can, reduce your selection set to just the ones you actually need.

Comment: I would add that when comparing two distinct AD objects using `-Properties *` there will _always_ be _some_ differences (e.g., distinguished name, GUID, SID, etc.). As Matt pointed out it is better to select the properties you really want to compare.

Comment: Note that `Out-File` formats things to fit the screen by default, but can be adjusted by using the `-width` parameter. Piping to `Out-File -Path $Path -Width 2147483647` should eliminate any truncation, assuming your lines are not more than 2,147,483,647 characters long. The parameter is a 32-bit int, so that is the largest number it will accept. I believe that you can do similar things on screen using `Out-String -Width 2147483647`. [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/cookbooks/redirecting-data-with-out---cmdlets?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: True. I didn't want to go on too much of a tangent since he shouldn't be using that here anyway.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed - I wasn't aware of the behavior of format-table and out-file. export-csv and format-list both work for me.

In this case I did need to list all the properties unfortunately, otherwise I would be able to use the builtin `compare-object`.